# Angular4 service with angularfire2 loss data after navigation

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-services

I'm using angularfire.
When I get data for first time it works OK and data is displayed but when I navigate to another page and then comeback to the same the data is lost unless I change something in firebase database or reload page.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Any help will be apreciate.

This is my retrieving data service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Band } from '../models/Band';

@Injectable()
export class UserBandsService {

    userBandCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Band>
    bands: Observable<Band[]>

  constructor(
      public afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
    this.userBandCollection = this.afs.collection('bands', ref => ref.where(
      'users.userRef', '==', 'k9JEqf4JhggNAeVT1POoN0nJC0u2'
      )
    );
    this.bands = this.userBandCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map( a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Band;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
      });
    });
  }

  getBands(){
    return this.bands;
  }
}
```

And the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserBandsService } from '../core/user-bands.service';

import { Band } from '../models/Band';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-bands',
  templateUrl: './user-bands.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-bands.component.css']
})
export class UserBandsComponent implements OnInit {

  userBands: Band[];

  constructor(
    private bandsService: UserBandsService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bandsService.getBands().subscribe(userBands => {
      if(userBands){
        this.userBands = userBands;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And the Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let band of userBands">
  {{band.estilo}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try using async pipe in your template instead of subscribing in `ngOnInit`? `userBands | async`. Also please include also template.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working.